# How to send post request with its json body?

Tags: url, post, postman, magento2

I have a JSON format body for a post request.

How to send the body in url without using postman?

Comment: Can you provide the work you have already?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Select Request method `POST` from the drop-down list

Step 2: In header add a key named `Content-Type` and `application/json` as it's value

Step 3: place your JSON string in the body and select `raw` from the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can not send json in url. It will be sent in the data part of your http request.
For sending a post request using postman follow steps below.

**Step 1:** Select Request method POST from the drop-down list.

**Step 2:** specify your request url in textbox for request url.

**Step 3:** select body option from tabs.

**Step 4:** select raw option from radio buttons.

**Step 5:** select JSON(application/json) from dropdown.

**Step 6:** paste your json in text area and press send button.